# Suicide to save someone's life

Tags: suicide

There was a killer who threatened me to perform murders with his gun. I thought about ending my life by his gun so I wouldn't be used for killing anyone.

Will allah forgive suicide in this case as I did it almost to save human lives.
Luckily I got out but just asking if he would have forgiven

Answer (score 1):

**NO.**

Committing suicide is a major sin according to Quran and Hadith. Paradise will be prohibited for those who commit suicide. Jundub ibn Abdullah (Ra) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said:

> "'A man among those who came before you was wounded. He panicked and
> took a knife and cut his hand, and the bleeding did not stop until he
> died.' Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, said, 'My slave
> hastened his death; I have forbidden Paradise to him."'
> **(Sahih Bukhari and Muslim)**

If a person kills himself with anything in this world, Allah will punish him with the means that he used to kill him. Thaabit ibn Dahhaak (Ra) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said:

> "Whoever kills himself with something will be punished with it on the
> Day of Resurrection."
> **(Sahih Bukhari)**

It is clearly known to us by another authentic narration that whoever commits suicide by throttling will keep on throttling himself in the Hellfire (forever) and he who commits suicide by stabbing himself will keep on stabbing himself in the Hellfire. Abu Hurayrah (Ra) narrated that the Prophet (PBUH) said:

> "Whoever throws himself down from a mountain and kills himself will be
> throwing himself down in the fire of hell forever and ever. Whoever
> drinks poison and kills himself will be sipping it in the fire of hell
> forever and ever. Whoever kills himself with a piece of iron will have
> that iron in his hand, thrusting it into his belly in the fire of hell
> forever and ever." 
> **(Sahih Muslim)**

Narrated by Anas Bin Malik the Prophet (PBUH) said:

> "None of you should wish for death because of a calamity befalling
> him; but if he has to wish for death, he should say, "O Allah! Keep me
> alive as long as life is better for me, and let me die if death is
> better for me." 
> **(Sahih Bukhari Book 70 Hadith 575)**

You should do your part and report such a person for nearly putting your life and people you know lives at risk. I pray Allah gives you and your family protection ameen.

Comment: But Allah says in Quran:(whoever saves a life, it will be as if they saved all of humanity.)(5:32) , so according to this verse he saves all of humanity.

Comment: @Anonymous that’s that doesn’t refer to a case where you intentionally kill yourself. Never ever come near suicide, it’s not a joke in Islam brother.